# How To write RegExpression For Not allow leading and ending space in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a Javascript RegExpression but i am not getting correct answer,
i am writing expression which

• No restrictions for input data.

• Starting and ending space is not allowed.

I wrote like /^\S*\S$/ but not getting correct output please help me.

Comment: `/^\s|\s$/.test(string)?' Starts or ends with space' : 'ok';`

Comment: can you please provide  example of data and the desired result? simply writing `/.+/g` will give all content without starting and ending space, or  `/\w+/g` will give each word of your content without the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it right, you just need a `.` before the `*`. This way it just checks the first and last characters are not whitespace, and allows anything in between. As you had it, every character in the string could not be whitespace so a string like `hello hello` would fail.

```
/^\S.*\S$/
```

[Working on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37bmr)

Comment: i thougth about that too in the first polace, but i guess its not what  he wanted.. he wants to detact strings with only leading, only trailing as well as both, leasding and trainling whitespaces.. so the solution in RobG's comment is correct

Comment: @nozzleman RobG's solution detects exactly the same condition as this, his is just the inverse (i.e. when mine returns true, his returns false). Checking `!a AND !b` is the inverse of checking `a OR b`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regeex for this. You can easily check if the first or the last character is a white space by simple using an `if`.

Something like this:

```
var input = " my text with whitespaces";

if(input[0] == " " || input[input.length-1] == " ") {
   console.log("error");
}
```

Substring version:

```
var input = " my text with whitespaces";

if(input.substring(0,1) == " " || input.substring(input.length-1, input.length) == " ") {
   console.log("error");
}
```

Comment: Not all browsers in use allow access to strings by index. An equivalent using `substring` should work fine though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
(/^\S+(?!.*\s$).*$/).test('my string')
```

`^\S+` match one char at the beginning of string that is not a whitespace

`(?!.*\s$)` negative lookahead for a whitespace at the end of the string

`.*` match anything else

This will evaluate to true if your string has whitespaces at the beginning or the end, and to false otherwise.

You can also do:

```
!(/^\s+|\s+$/).test('my string')
```

Which may be more readable depending on knowledge of regular expressions.